# How to capture the range of non-sequential numbers in r

Tags: r, time-series, data-manipulation

I'm working with time-series data that looks like this:

```
     Missing_Years       cname
1263          1960 Afghanistan
1264          1961 Afghanistan
1265          1962 Afghanistan
1266          1963 Afghanistan
1267          1964 Afghanistan
1268          1997 Afghanistan
1269          1998 Afghanistan
1270          1999 Afghanistan
1271          2000 Afghanistan
1272          2001 Afghanistan
1273          2002 Afghanistan
1274          2003 Afghanistan
1275          2004 Afghanistan
1276          2005 Afghanistan
```

What I would like is a data set that notes the name of the country and the range of the years. If you notice, the dates are not sequential. So using the `range` function alone would be inaccurate. This is the tricky part.

I would like the output to look something like this:

```
   cname          Missing_Years
Afghanistan       1960 - 1964 
Afghanistan       1997 - 2005
```

Please note that I'll be looping over countries. So any code that can be fashioned to do so would be much appreciated.

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out the rows where sequence breaks using `diff` and use it as a grouping variable.

```
df$group <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df$Missing_Years) > 1))
aggregate(Missing_Years~cname+group, df, function(x) paste(range(x),collapse = "-"))
```

---

Or using `dplyr` we can compare the values using `lag`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(cname,grp = cumsum(Missing_Years-lag(Missing_Years,default = 0) > 1)) %>%
  summarise(Missing_Years = paste(range(Missing_Years),  collapse = "-")) %>%
  select(-grp)

#  cname       Missing_Years
#  <fct>       <chr>        
#1 Afghanistan 1960-1964    
#2 Afghanistan 1997-2005
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Missing_Years = c(1960L, 1961L, 1962L, 1963L, 
1964L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2005L), cname = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Afghanistan", class = "factor")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-14L))
```

Comment: For the base R method, I'm getting the following error:```> df$group <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df$Missing_Years) > 1))
Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator```

Comment: @SharifAmlani Probably `Missing_Years` is factor. Change it to numeric by doing `df$Missing_Years <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Missing_Years))` and try again.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` as well

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(cname = first(cname), Missing_Years = paste(range(Missing_Years),
      collapse="_")), .(grp = cumsum(Missing_Years - shift(Missing_Years, 
         fill = first(Missing_Years)) > 1 ))][, grp := NULL][]
#         cname Missing_Years
#1: Afghanistan     1960_1964
#2: Afghanistan     1997_2005
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Missing_Years = c(1960L, 1961L, 1962L, 1963L, 
1964L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2005L), cname = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Afghanistan", class = "factor")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-14L))
```